# Extracting instructions from an ELF file

Tags: c, assembly, elf, riscv

For a program I'm working on, I need to extract the instructions of an ELF binary compiled for the risc-v arch.
The way i'm trying to extract the instructions is the following:

```
void dumpCode(FILE *file, Elf32_Phdr *segm, Elf32_Ehdr *header)
{
    char *fileptr;
    struct stat statbuf;
    int *opcode_ptr;
    unsigned int i, vaddr, offset;

    int fd = fileno(file);
    if (fstat(fd, &statbuf)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error while stating the file!\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    fileptr = (char *)mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    if (MAP_FAILED == fileptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error mapping the file!\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    offset = (0 == segm->p_offset ? header->e_ehsize + header->e_phnum * header->e_phentsize : segm->p_offset); // Mark 1

    opcode_ptr = (int *)(fileptr + offset);

    vaddr = (0 == segm->p_offset ? segm->p_vaddr + header->e_ehsize + header->e_phnum * header->e_phentsize : segm->p_vaddr); // Mark 2

    for (i = 0; i < segm->p_filesz / 4; i++, vaddr += 4) { // Mark 3
        unsigned char *opcode = getOpcode(*opcode_ptr++);
        if (1 == disas(opcode, vaddr)) {
            free(opcode);
            break;
        }
        free(opcode);
    }

    munmap(fileptr, statbuf.st_size);
fail:
    close(fd);
}
```

To test my function, first I wrote a simple assembly program:

```
.global _start

_start:
    addi a0, x0, 1
    la a1, str
    addi a2, x0, 6
    addi a7, x0, 64
    ecall

    addi a0, x0, 0
    addi a7, x0, 93
    ecall

.data
    str: .ascii "Hello\n"
```

As a second test file I wrote a different code, this time in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%.5f", sqrt(2.0));
    return 0;
}
```

The first test file has been compiled and assembled using: `riscv32-linux-gnu-as -o test1.o test1.s; riscv32-linux-gnu-ld -o test1 test1.o`
The second test file has been compiled directly with gcc `riscv32-linux-gnu-gcc -o test2 test2.c -lm`
Returning to the *dumpCode* function, I've marked three lines.

1. The first line is the offset where the segment is placed inside the file, in case it's 0, if i'm not wrong I need to add (header->e_ehsize + header->e_phnum * header->e_phentsize) bytes in order to start dumping at the right place. Using this approach, with my test1 example it work's, but when i'm using the second test file it doesn't work. The second mark follow the same approach as this one, to extract the right virtual address.
2. The third mark is placed in the for loop i'm using to iterate over the instructions, but using (segm->p_filesz / 4) to count the exact number of instructions presents in the binary, it gives me much more instructions. As far as I know, the extra data belongs to padding, but I would like to know if I could stop prcessing data when arrived to the padding section.

How could I calculate the right amount of bytes I need to process from the elf file? If that amount of bytes includes padding, could I ignore it somehow?

Comment: 1/ Doesn't work _how_? What result does it give? What result should it have given? You can disassemble your program with `objdump` for comparison and see the correct offset there.

Comment: 2/ Please don't ask multiple questions, since you can only accept one answer. In any case, you should at least say what the extra instructions _are_ and how the output compares to `objdump` again.

Comment: There is no actual question in your post; none of the sentences is interrogative or is marked with a question mark. Stack Overflow is for asking a specific question, not for dumping code and asking what is wrong with it multiple parts of it. And when code does need debugging, there are guidelines that should be followed, such as providing a [mre].

Comment: @Useless I have disassembled it with objdump and I have compared the output my program gives with the one given by objd. The output of my program is the same as the objd. The extra instructions doesn't appear in objdump so I can't compare

Comment: so for starters you are using readelf to examine the data in the elf file then you are writing your own program to isolate the loadable parts?  Or specifically .text? (not nearly enough code to isolate .text)

Comment: Just curious if the extra instructions appear in `objdump` if you use the `-z` option.

Comment: @old_timer I'm trying to extract .text only

Comment: @MichaelPetch no, nothing extra appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

```
offset = (0 == segm->p_offset
    ? header->e_ehsize + header->e_phnum * header->e_phentsize
    : segm->p_offset); // Mark 1
```

This is wrong. The document is very specific:

> ```
>   p_offset
>          This member holds the offset from the beginning of the
>          file at which the first byte of the segment resides.
> ```

The data starts at segm->p_offset. No ifs or buts.

If you are seeing 0, I suspect it is because the segment doesn't have the `PT_LOAD` flag, meaning it's not in the file at all (and the offset in the file doesn't make sense) **or** because the segment is supposed to contain the ELF header (so offset 0 isn't wrong).

---

There is no distinction to the CPU between instructions and non-instructions. Every 4 bytes could possibly be an instruction. Even 00000000 is an instruction. An instruction is whatever the program counter points to. You could try to figure out where the program counter can point, but that's equivalent to the halting problem, therefore impossible.

There **may** be debug information or symbols that say which say which part of the file is padding, but since the CPU doesn't care, neither does the main part of the ELF file.

Comment: I believed that a  segment couldn't contain the ELF header so that's why I added the if

Comment: @Josep you just assumed it meant some random address?

Comment: No, I assumed it because in the pictures i've seen, first is represented the elf header, then pht and finally section 1, section n. And what i believed was that segments are composed by one or more sections